# Django: UpdateView - dispatch : reduce the number of queries

Tags: django, django-orm, django-class-based-views

I have a Product Model, foreign key to Company Model, onetoone key to User.

I override the dispatch(method) to check if the user has rights to edit the object(product).

I'm trying to optimize the queries to the database because some of them are duplicates.

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = self.get_object()
    if obj.company.user != request.user:
        raise PermissionDenied
    else:
        print('ok')
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, *kwargs)
```

query to products

```
obj = self.get_object()
```

query to company and query to user twice

```
if obj.company.user != request.user:
```

query to products again

```
 return super().dispatch(request, *args, *kwargs)
```

How can I optimize and remove duplicated queries ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can prevent one of the user queries by comparing ids instead of model instances.

```
if obj.company.user_id != request.user.id:
```

Reducing the number of queries further is trickier. In practice, removing the duplicate queries will not have a noticeable effect, and it probably isn't worth complicating your code to do.

To prevent the duplicate object lookup, you can cache the object as `self.object`.

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.obj = self.get_object()
        if obj.company.user != request.user:
        raise PermissionDenied
```

Then override then `get_object` to check the cache first.

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    obj = getattr(self, 'object', None)
    if obj is None:
        obj = super().get_object(queryset)
    return obj
```

You could probably get rid of the company query by using `select_related()` when fetching the object. Again, this will make the code more complicated, and probably isn't worth doing.